# Comparing signed hex numbers

Tags: java, signed, hex, javacard

I have to use ints in java card but since the card itself does not support integers I use byte[] instead.

To represent numbers in hexadecimal format I check the first bit, if it is 1 - negative, if it is 0 - positive (binary wise). So if the leading bit is smaller than 8 it is positive, otherwise negative (hex wise).

Highest number: 7FFFFFFF

Lowest number: 80000000

Now I am wondering if I want to compare a value eg. 00000001 if it is to high/low, do I check without the most significant bit (FFFFFFF > 0000001 > 0000000) and check the most significant bit seperately (if > 7 => negative, else => positive) or is there a "smoother" way to do it?

Comment: I assume you mean you want to compare *two* values?  If so, the canonical way is to subtract them and see what the resulting sign is.

Comment: well I want to know if a number is in between the boundaries and is positive or negative

Comment: What boundaries?  If a signed number is 32 bits it's between 7FFFFFFF and 80000000 -- nothing to check.

Comment: but how does the number knows if it is signed in a byte array? I guess that has to be done manually or am I overcomplicating things?

Comment: You need to DEFINE whether the number is signed or not.  How do you know that an `int` is signed in C?  Because you defined it `int` and not `unsigned int`.

Comment: sure I usually define if it should be unsigned, but I am using a byte[] representation of an 32 bit signed integer and thus the comparison of two byte[] values: 80000000 < 00000000 will not be true even the first represents a negative number

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947638/simulate-int-variables-with-byte-or-short

Comment: @UmNyobe Darn. maybe I'll host it somewhere the X-mas 2013 :P Should work though.

Comment: Hexadecimals is the encoding of binary data into two hexadecimal characters 0..F per byte. It's a string representation of the binary data. You don't want to compare hexadecimals, you want to compare two byte arrays (binary data) that contain a signed, big endian, two-complement number each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you may not want to have the overhead of comparing using [JCInteger given in this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14027143/589259). If you just want to compare two signed, two complement, big endian numbers (the default Java integer encoding) in a byte array, then you can use the following code:

```
/**
 * Compares two signed, big endian integers stored in a byte array at a specific offset.
 * @param n1 the buffer containing the first number
 * @param n1Offset the offset of the first number in the buffer
 * @param n2 the buffer containing the second number
 * @param n2Offset the offset in the buffer of the second number
 * @return -1 if the first number is lower, 0 if the numbers are equal or 1 if the first number is greater
 */
public final static byte compareSignedInteger(
        final byte[] n1, final short n1Offset,
        final byte[] n2, final short n2Offset) {

    // compare the highest order byte (as signed)
    if (n1[n1Offset] < n2[n2Offset]) {
        return -1;
    } else if (n1[n1Offset] > n2[n2Offset]) {
        return +1;
    }

    // compare the next bytes (as unsigned values)
    short n1Byte, n2Byte;
    for (short i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        n1Byte = (short) (n1[(short) (n1Offset + i)] & 0xFF);
        n2Byte = (short) (n2[(short) (n2Offset + i)] & 0xFF);

        if (n1Byte < n2Byte) {
            return -1;
        } else if (n1Byte > n2Byte) {
            return +1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this code is not optimized, it may be faster to *unroll* the loop, and it should be possible to do this with just byte arithmetic.

Comment: Tested with a million random numbers, and a million tests with MIN, -1, 0, +1 and MAX value. Offsets not tested, but hey...